# Filtering git commits from repository

Tags: git

`git log` outputs something like this:

```
commit 6c.................................c1d6
Author: Alice <alice@email.address>
Date:   Wed Feb 5 10:04:05 2014 +0200

    Commit message

commit f8...................................d5719
Author: Bob <bob@email.address>
Date:   Fri Jan 31 00:35:48 2014 +0100

    Commit message

...
```

How can I get all `Alice`'s commits made in `Friday` days?

I tried to use `grep`:

```
git log | grep "Fri"
```

But this outputs this:

```
Date:   Fri Jan 31 00:35:48 2014 +0100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all of Alice's commits with `git log --author Alice` but there is no built in way to limit the output to certain weekdays.

Try

```
git log --author Alice --pretty='format:%h %cd' | grep Fri
```

EDIT: Ok, try this for a complete git-log like output:

```
git log --author=Alice --pretty='%H %cd' | grep Fri | awk '{ print $1 }' | while read rev; do git show -s --pretty=medium $rev | cat; echo; done
```

Comment: +1, Helpful but this still doesn't show the full commit information like in `git log`.